# How to add php to javascript google tag

Tags: javascript, php

Please help me check this js, i want to add .php in javascript for gtag js, but my code fails.
This is the google tag:

```
<script>gtag('event', 'page_view', {
'send_to': 'AW-xxx',
'ecomm_pagetype': 'replace with value',
'ecomm_prodid': 'replace with value',
'ecomm_totalvalue': 'replace with value' });</script>
```

And here is my code:

```
<script>
      gtag('event', 'page_view', {
        'send_to': 'AW-xxx',
        'ecomm_prodid': ' . json_encode( $this->mc_prefix . ( 0 == $this->product_identifier ? get_the_ID() : $product->get_sku() ) ) . ',
        'ecomm_pagetype': \'product\',
        'ecomm_totalvalue': ' . $product->get_price() . '
    };
</script>
```

I use WooCommerce AdWords Dynamic Remarketing plugin.

---

This is my code, please check at line 455

[My Full Code](https://gist.github.com/heartbreaker1102/85fd044c878393895e678643a04f1dca)

Comment: If you want to add php variables to your script then you should use the `<?php` `?>` tags to indicate where they start. Otherwise javascript just thinks they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open and close the PHP tag in order to use PHP functions and variables, like so:

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'page_view', {
        'send_to': 'AW-xxx',
        'ecomm_prodid': '<?php echo json_encode( $this->mc_prefix . ( 0 == $this->product_identifier ? get_the_ID() : $product->get_sku() ) ); ?>',
        'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
        'ecomm_totalvalue': '<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>'
    };
</script>
```

---

Edit:

So the above is actually invalid since the script is being created inside a PHP variable. Replace lines 455 to 463 of your gist with the following:

```
$product_id_code = '
    <script>
        gtag("event", "page_view", {
            "send_to": "'.json_encode($this->conversion_id, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ).'",
            "ecomm_prodid": "'.json_encode($this->mc_prefix.(0 == $this->product_identifier ? get_the_ID() : $product->get_sku())).'",
            "ecomm_pagetype": "product",
            "ecomm_totalvalue": "'.$product->get_price().'"
        });
    </script>
';
```

Comment: ops ! 500 error after add your code :d
By the way, thank alot !

Comment: Is the file you are adding this script to, end in `.php`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/heartbreaker1102/85fd044c878393895e678643a04f1dca

Comment: Thank @GaryThomas very much :d. i did it !